# Where does the alpha band go when a geotiff is turned into a brick in R? How to get false color composite?

Tags: r, r-raster

I'm trying to isolate impervious surfaces with open source software. Everything with remote sensing tools so far has errored out to a point I cannot get around. 
But I believe in R! I have a .tif and in gdal it shows all four bands, R,G,B, and alpha. But when I bring it into R as anything, brick, stack or raster... I don't see the alpha band..It's only showing R,G,B and I'd like to get a false color composite, which is not working out. I think this is because of the missing alpha band.? Is there a way to adjust wavelengths in R?
Thanks in advance for any help!

```
The tiff in gdal:

C:\>gdalinfo tgeotiff.tif

Size is 6964, 9787
Coordinate System is:
Metadata:
Image Structure Metadata:

Band 1 Block=6964x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Description = Band #1
  Min=8.000 Max=247.000
  Minimum=8.000, Maximum=247.000, Mean=84.884, StdDev=54.598
  Overviews: 3482x4894, 1741x2447, 871x1224, 436x612, 218x306
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
  Overviews of mask band: 3482x4894, 1741x2447, 871x1224, 436x612, 218x306
  Metadata:
    DESCRIPTION=Band #1

Band 2 Block=6964x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Description = Band #2
  Min=13.000 Max=246.000
  Minimum=13.000, Maximum=246.000, Mean=103.650, StdDev=53.246
  Overviews: 3482x4894, 1741x2447, 871x1224, 436x612, 218x306
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
  Overviews of mask band: 3482x4894, 1741x2447, 871x1224, 436x612, 218x306
  Metadata:
    DESCRIPTION=Band #2

Band 3 Block=6964x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Description = Band #3
  Min=22.000 Max=241.000
  Minimum=22.000, Maximum=241.000, Mean=85.311, StdDev=36.438
  Overviews: 3482x4894, 1741x2447, 871x1224, 436x612, 218x306
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
  Overviews of mask band: 3482x4894, 1741x2447, 871x1224, 436x612, 218x306
  Metadata:
    DESCRIPTION=Band #3

Band 4 Block=6964x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
  Description = Band #4
  Min=0.000 Max=244.000
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=244.000, Mean=130.583, StdDev=67.373
  Overviews: 3482x4894, 1741x2447, 871x1224, 436x612, 218x306
  Metadata:

The tiff in R:

r <- brick('tGeotiff')

r

class       : RasterBrick 
dimensions  : 195567, 73747, 14422479549, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 0.3, 0.3  (x, y)
extent      : 7268775, 7290899, 340179.9, 398850  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=lcc +lat_1=44.33333333333334 +lat_2=46 +lat_0=43.66666666666666 +lon_0=-120.5 +x_0=2500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +units=ft +no_defs 
data source : C:\Users\tGeotiff 
names       : **tGeotiff.1, tGeotiff.2, tGeotiff.3** 
min values  :                  0,                  0,                  0 
max values  :                255,                255,                255
```

Comment: Do you know there's a package called `rgdal`? Anyhow, read this http://neondataskills.org/R/Multi-Band-Rasters-In-R/

Comment: Yes and I believe I needed that package to bring the data into a "brick" to use the raster in r, but the alpha layer seems to not be there...

Comment: whatabout `tiff` package? I usually use ArcGIS (`arcpy`) for these tasks but I believe `tiff` brings alpha as well.

Comment: With the data or an example, this would be easier to help you. Normally if you call your file using `raster::stack(filename)` this should import all layers available.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I edited the above note to show what I'm seeing. It may be there, I've only just begun working with spatial data in R. But it looks like the alpha band goes away. I used raster::stack(filename) too StatnMap and got the same results as above. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'd include the data but it's basically my home town.

Comment: Why do you need the alpha band for a false colour composite?

Comment: I think I need the fourth band to get a false colour composite. Isn't it 4, 3,2 to get it? I've tried every combo of the three bands and cannot get the vegetation to turn red... And I wouldn't mind trying to look at it as NDVI which also requires the fourth band I believe

Comment: Let's start from the top: Which sensor are you using, aka which satellite image are you looking at? This will tell you, which bands you'll need for making a FC-Composite. Then there's another topic of an alpha band ... these are not related to the sensor, hence you don't need them for making a  composite.

Comment: Its a landsat image I translated from a mrsid to a geotiff.

Comment: If it's landsat-8, you should have 11 bands in the original image. For making a FC-Composite, you would need to extract bands 5,4,3 and stack them together in this order

Comment: Ah! I guess the original is actually orthoimagery! It pays to ask twice! I have the .tiff tiles. I could start from scratch and mosaic them together. Maybe something was lost in the compression because the MrSid version only has three bands also. FC-Composite would be great to contrast the vegetation vs urban. Hoping to extract the  impervious surfaces... Thanks again Val!